# Pages for the Community Blog

Tags: discussion, blog

The [About Page of the Community Blog](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/about/) still looks sketchy.  Joe and I could put together some text for it.  Beyond that, though, I'd like to ask what additional pages, if any, might be useful.

One suggestion of mine: once we have a list of TCS conferences and workshops "at equilibrium" we add it to a static page on the blog.  This page would include the Conference Calendar link suggested/produced by Jukka.

Agreement, disagreement?  Other suggestions for blog pages?

Comment: I like the idea of adding the TCS conferences/workshops page.

Comment: Just take care not to turn it into a duplicate of [Theory Matters](http://theorymatters.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php).

Comment: One more thing, some (famous) theory bloggers have kindly linked to the blog (e.g. Lance and Bill), I think it might be nice to link back to them (and maybe also to other famous theory blogs).

Comment: @Kaveh: adding to the blogroll makes sense, but I don't understand the other point. Redundancy seems like a service not a problem with this kind of information, and I don't see how a static blog page could ever duplicate a wiki page, except maybe temporarily.

Comment: IMHO, "redundancy" is a problem, it scatters information, and keeping the information up to date becomes more difficult. E.g., a central place like [this](http://intractability.princeton.edu/jobs/) where everyone would advertise theory positions is better than 10 pages/mailing lists/... each having 20 percent of the advertisements. I think we should link to them if they are kept more or less up to date in place of duplicating them when possible.

Comment: a little off-topic, but not sure if I should make it a separate blog-related question: we don't seem to show up on the front page of http://blogoverflow.com/  does anybody know why?

Comment: @Artem, I don't know why but personally I won't mind it if they don't list our blog there. :)

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: That's a good question: maybe post a new meta question ?

Comment: I think the text of the link "Theoretical Computer Science Conferences and Workshops" is too long, maybe you should use something shorter like "TCS Conferences".

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of the TCS conferences link, I wonder if it might be useful to have a "Career advice" page that points to the relevant questions on the site about career decisions ? This could also have a link to the CRA jobs page.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good idea.

Comment: -1 I would prefer a more person blogpost by a senior researcher (as opposed to a static page on which it is not clear who the advice is coming through; even though it might be the same senior researcher) with links to relevant questions in that post, and the links to general career advice can be placed in 'resource page' as suggested by Joe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to add a resources page, linking to various TCS resources available on the web. I know we have some of these in the FAQ, but it might be good to make a fuller list. I had in mind places like the zoo, as well as the open problems pages, etc.

Comment: whoops, misread the answer. I agree that we should have on general resources page. For open problems, I suggest http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/ it's CS coverage is soso right now, but we could improve that by posting some open questions from cstheory, I think they have pretty good coverage of open problems in the related fields of combinatorics and discrete math.

Answer (score 2):

I liked the Contributors page that the TeX blog has:

http://tex.blogoverflow.com/contributors/

I think we should have one, too.

Comment: I think we are to early for this, given that we are continually soliciting material from the community.

Comment: Having said that, we already have 5 contributors to the blog, and the texblog has (only) 6.

Comment: @Suresh: Exactly. I think the way we are currently running the blog means we will have far more contributors than them, and so a contributors page will be less practical to maintain.

Comment: I see. definitely no harm in waiting a bit.